# Inserting chunked values from a self join in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

So, I have a query that contains a self join and is chunked. I tried to run the query, but I get:

> Call to undefined method stdClass::pluck()

```
DB::table('locations as u1')
        ->join('locations as u2','u1.id', '<>', 'u2.id')
        ->whereNotExists(function($query)
        {
            $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                ->from('routes')
                ->whereRaw('routes.from_id = u1.id')
                ->whereRaw('routes.to_id = u2.id');
        })->orderBy('u1.id')->chunk(5000, function ($routes) {
        foreach ($routes as $route){
            $db = new Route;
            $db->from_id = $route->pluck('u1.id');
            $db->to_id = $route->pluck('u2.id');
            $db->distance = Flow::GIS('OSRM')->route($route->pluck('u1.name'),$route->pluck('u2.name'))->distance();
            $db->save();
        }
    });
```

How do I select in a foreach loop the **u1.id,u2.id,u1.name,u2.name**?The result is 1.500.000 row big, so doing it without chunking is bad.I'm using Postgres as my database.

Comment: From the doc, pluck is used only on collections. I suppose $route is not a collection.

Comment: @Vincent Decaux I understand It, but how to get these values into the foreach loop? It's ment to be just an Idea. Is there a trick to select the location as components?

Comment: What does $route contain ?

Comment: @Vincent Decaux It contains the chunked locations collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Select method to affect an alias to your selected rows (u1.id, u2.id, u1.name, u2.name) and then use that alias to get your data:

```
DB::table('locations as u1')
    ->join('locations as u2','u1.id', '<>', 'u2.id')
    ->whereNotExists(function($query)  {
        $query->select(DB::raw(1))
            ->from('routes')
            ->whereRaw('routes.from_id = u1.id')
            ->whereRaw('routes.to_id = u2.id');
    })
    ->select( \DB::raw("u1.id as u1id, u2.id as u2.id, u1.name as u1name, u2.name as u2name") )
    ->orderBy('u1.id')
    ->chunk(5000, function ($routes) {
        foreach ($routes as $route){
            $db = new Route;
            $db->from_id = $route->u1id;
            $db->to_id = $route->u2id;
            $db->distance = Flow::GIS('OSRM')->route($route->u1name, $route->u2name)->distance();
            $db->save();
        }
    });
```

Note: pluck method is only available for collections, in your foreach you are getting each row as object (stdClass)

Comment: the hero we need but don't deserve. Thank you alot :D!